# Image uploads in Rails with jQuery plugins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have a create prouct page and an add photos page. After a user creates a product they get redirected to a page that allows them to add photos. I'm using [Jquery file-upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) which shows a preview of the pictures you selected and then upon clicking start adds them to the server. However, I get this error.

**jQuery file-upload error**

> DWadeCrop.jpg   97.74 KB  Error SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

**Console message**

```
Started POST "/photos" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-10 21:03:03 -0400
Processing by PhotosController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"tc6sbe9n/PPKlZlUpQYWqxR3C6QJEMnQJSKr8+prczw=", "product_id"=>"129", "photo"=>{"upload"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xa5f0780 @original_filename="DWadeCrop.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo[upload]\"; filename=\"DWadeCrop.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20130710-3967-h6rcoo>>}}
Product Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "129"]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-10 21:03:03 -0400
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as JSON
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.haml within layouts/application (1.4ms)
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."auth_token" = 'eQOQkRRSnzfA51iiDQ-90w' LIMIT 1
Completed 200 OK in 85ms (Views: 84.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

**Upload photo view** Location localhost:3000/products/123/pics

```
Upload file
  = form_for @photo, :html => { :multipart => true, :id => "fileupload"  } do |f|
    = f.file_field :upload
    = hidden_field_tag 'product_id', @photo.product_id
```

**method for pics**

```
  def pics
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @photo = Photo.new
    @photo.product_id = @product.id
  end
```

**create method for photos**

```
def create
  @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  @photo = Photo.new

  if @photo.valid?
    @photo.product_id = @product.id
    @photo.save!
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to product_path(@product) }
      format.json { render json: @photo }
    end
  else
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Somehting went wrong!"
  end
 end
```

**Photo model**

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :image
  has_attached_file :image

  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  belongs_to :product
    validates_attachment :image, presence: true,
                            content_type: { content_type: ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/gif'] },
                            size: { less_than: 5.megabytes }
    has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "320x240>", :thumb => "100x100>"}

      def to_jq_image
    {
      "name" => read_attribute(:upload_file_name),
      "size" => read_attribute(:upload_file_size),
      "url" => image.url(:original),
      "delete_type" => "DELETE" 
    }
  end

end
```

Comment: Do you use any gem for fileupload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your photo model you have

```
  "name" => read_attribute(:upload_file_name),
  "size" => read_attribute(:upload_file_size),
```

when your model is @photo so change this to

```
  "name" => read_attribute(:photo_file_name),
  "size" => read_attribute(:photo_file_size),
```

Also in your form_for you have

```
Upload file
  = form_for @photo, :html => { :multipart => true, :id => "fileupload"  } do |f|
    = f.file_field :upload
```

Where  it says :upload  again your model is @photo replace that as well.